# Plsql statements not working with ANT

Tags: sql, ant, plsql, sqlplus

I have a file with the following content:

> -- KERNEL72 - SWIFT Silver changes start
>
> /*
>
> drop synonym ispkss_vals
>   /
>
> create synonym ispkss_vals for ispks_vals
>   /
>
> */-- KERNEL72 - SWIFT Silver changes ends after the below line
>
> create or replace synonym ispkss_vals for ispks_vals
>   /

This is compiling properly in SQL Plus. But while compiling using ANT, I am getting the following error:

> ```
> [sql] Failed to execute:
> ```
>
> [sql] -- KERNEL72 - SWIFT Silver changes start
>   [sql] /*
>   [sql] drop synonym ispkss_vals
>   [sql] java.sql.SQLException: Invalid SQL type
>   [sql] Failed to execute:
>   [sql] create synonym ispkss_vals for ispks_vals
>   [sql] java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
>   [sql] Failed to execute:
>   [sql] */-- KERNEL72 - SWIFT Silver changes ends after the below line
>   [sql] create or replace synonym ispkss_vals for ispks_vals
>   [sql] java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Im using the following ANT scripts for compilation:

```
                  <sql driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.184.1.13:1521:UPP"
        userid="${UsernameB}"
        password="${PasswordB}"
        onerror="continue"
        strictDelimiterMatching="false"
        delimiter="/"
        keepformat="yes">
```

Please advice on why ANT compilations are not proper.

Comment: why do you specify `delimiter=";"` if you are clearly using `/` as the delimiter?

Comment: Sorry. It was a mistake while copying the code. delimiter is / only. corrected above.

Comment: Have you tried running the script without the header?  Because it appears to be ignoring the comment notation and executing the redundant statements.  Besides, commenting out code is a poor substitute for *decent source control* and *a clean code-base*.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the problem is that you are using `/` as the statement delimiter and also trying to comment with `/* ... */`?

It may be treating the comment opening and closing as delimiters, creating sql statements that don't make sense.  (one would start with `*`, etc.)

Comment: This seems the most likely answer.